# Force AWS SQS to process messages one by one

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS FIFO that triggers lambda to process the messages.
How I can force SQS FIFO to process message exactly one by one.
So message number 1 -> lambda completed and only after lambda execution completed proceed with message number 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the SQS Lambda integration Batch Size setting to `1` and the Lambda Function's [Concurrency Limit](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/) to `1`.